# How to keep PowerShell commands (History up key) Per Project in VS code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I really like the up key history in VS Code terminal, but I work on different types of projects and often see irrelevant history for some projects. Can I set the terminal to keep my history on a per project/workspace basis?

Comment: It might be rather complex to implement that per project history persistence (for example, for PowerShell alone, manipulating `(Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath` requires much more efforts), but you can raise a feature request to VSCode GitHub repo and see what they say.

Comment: how would you that with PowerShell terminals you launch yourself

Answer (score 1):

See this same issue: [Per workspace terminal history](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102475).  No built-in fix though.  But there was a link to a workaround:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204928, so, for example, with zsh:

> With zsh, you could do:
>
> `mkdir -p ~/.zsh/dirhist`
>
> And add to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=10000
setopt HIST_SAVE_NO_DUPS INC_APPEND_HISTORY
HISTFILE=~/.zsh/dirhist/${PWD//\//@}
chpwd() {
  [[ $PWD = $OLDPWD ]] || fc -Pp ~/.zsh/dirhist/${PWD//\//@}
}
```

> `chpwd()` is called whenever the current directory changes. There, we
> reset the history file to something like `~/.zsh/dirhist/@foo@bar`
> when you `cd` to `/foo/bar`.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way would be to invoke Start-Transcript when you have specific output to keep. This is not as convenient as up-arrow, but at least you can separate out specific history. It works fine from the command line or a script, and you can define the name and path of the output:

```
$hist = "<path to specific file>-$(get-date -f ddMMMyy)-project-name.txt"
Start-Transcript -Path $hist -Append 
.
. working at the CLI or script is running
.
Stop-Transcript
```

One parameter that Start-Transcript takes will control how much header info is in the log, which can save space is -UseMinimalHeader.

Just remember to run Stop-Transcript and start a new file when you are done with the project you are working in or all the keyboard input will land in the same history file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7.3